# remove duplicate records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which have two colums,  id  and date. Here is same samples data.

```
ID          DATE
1           01-Jan -14 05.42.23.000000000 pm
1           01-Jan -14 05.06.17.000000000 pm
2           01-Jan -14 05.26.16.000000000 pm
2           01-Jan -14 05.41.20.000000000 pm
3           01-Jan -14 05.21.19.000000000 pm
3           01-Jan -14 05.08.18.000000000 pm
4           01-Jan -14 05.14.17.000000000 pm
4           01-Jan -14 05.17.17.000000000 pm
```

Column `ID` has duplicate data which need to remove, I want to keep rows which column `DATE` is bigger.

I write SQL but the result is not correct.

```
delete from newproducts a
 where a.id in
       (select t.id from newproducts t group by t.id having count(*) > 1)
   and a.date not in
       (select max(t.date) from newproducts  t group by t.id having count(*) > 1);
```

how to correct? Thanks

Comment: Noooooooo! not another delete duplicate question!  How do we delete duplicate "delete duplicate" questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for sql server;

```
delete a from newproducts as a
 where 
exists(
select * from newproducts b
where a.id = b.id and a.date < b.date)
```

Same or following should work on oracle;

```
delete from newproducts a
 where 
exists(
select * from newproducts b
where a.id = b.id and a.date < b.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `exists` subquery:

```
delete from newproducts np
    where not exists (select 1
                      from newproducts np2
                      where np2.id = np.id and np2.date > np.date
                     );
```